# Software under LGPL and API under GPL, which license do addons follow?

Tags: gpl-3, lgpl

In a specific case where the software is licensed under LGPL but its API is licensed under GPL, which of these should addons (that use the API) follow?
Additionally, if it's LGPL are addons required to follow the same license (or compatible ones) like they would under GPL?

The project for reference here is: Minecraft's Spigot, where the server implementation CraftBukkit is under LGPL but the API Bukkit is under GPL. https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT

Comment: The copyrightability of APIs is something under debate; could you please give a link to the exact project you're talking about?

Comment: @PhilipKendall The project is Minecraft's `Spigot`, where the server implementation CraftBukkit is under LGPL but the API Bukkit is under GPL. https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT

Comment: You describe Bukkit as an API, and I can see that their readme does as well. But I'm having a hard time accepting [this file](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Location.java) (to pick on a random example) as "API code." It looks a lot more like an implementation to me.

Answer (score -2):

Anything that uses GNU GPL-licensed software must be licensed under the GNU GPL or a compatible license.